# what's different with windowShouldClose and windowWillClose?

Tags: objective-c, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

From the names , one is  will  , one is should  ,
When I implement windowShouldClose  it worked fine.
When I implement windowWillClose    it worked fine.

But , when I implement two of them  , only windowShouldClose work  , why?

Answer (score 2):

In Cocoa it is a common pattern to have `...should...` delegate methods that return a `BOOL`. The delegate is asking you if it *should* do something. When it gets your answer back if checks if you think it should do it and then it *informs* you that it *will* do something (if you said YES). Later you get a third callback that it *did* do something (when it is finishes).